# How can I make tmux tell bash to display the *logical* version of the current directory in newly opened windows?

Tags: bash, tmux, cd-command

**Background**

I'm using tmux 2.0, Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS in VirtualBox.

In order to make tmux open new windows with the same path as the current window I added this line to my `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
bind c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

Note that in tmux, if I `cd` from home to a subdirectory *via a symlink*, then check `pwd` and `pwd -P` I get:

```
~$ cd pythons
~/pythons$               # An awesome prompt

~/pythons$ pwd           # According to "man pwd" this shows the "logical" path
/home/qiime/pythons

~/pythons$ pwd -P        # and this shows the "physical" path
/media/sf_Google_Drive/Home/Programs/Pythons
```

**The problem is**

If I open a *new* tmux window while in `~/pythons` the new bash prompt takes on the *physical* path:

```
/media/sf_Google_Drive/Home/Programs/Pythons$     # Not an awesome prompt
```

**Q:** Yes, it's opened to the *correct* directory... but is there a way to get tmux to start bash with the *logical* path instead of the full-blown *physical* path?

Alternatively, perhaps there is something I can add to `.bashrc` to make this happen?

**Edit:**

To check if any config settings are causing this issue I tried commenting out all lines in `~/.tmux.conf` except for

```
bind c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

but I still get the full physical path. I also tried `echo`ing the current (logical) path from the top of my `~/.bashrc` file. Unfortunately, this echos the ugly physical path of the parent window, which apparently has become the new window's physical *and* logical path. So tmux 2.0 must be passing it to the new bash instance via the value of `"#{pane_current_path}"`

Moreover, I just found this recently opened tmux issue: [pane_current_path doesn't agree with pane's PWD #33](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/33) indicating that this behavior originates in tmux code.

**Q:** So maybe my question should be, Is there a workaround?

Comment: You should check `.bashrc` or other sourced files.

Comment: @HongxuChen That won't help: it's tmux doing that before it starts bash, bash doesn't know which path was previously used inside tmux.

Comment: I'm using zsh and tmux and it prompts logical path for symlink files. Can you paste `~/.tmux.conf` ?

Comment: My `~/.tmux.conf` doesn't contain anything fancy but I did check if it was a problem. Please see edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me.

To `~/.bashrc`, add the line:

```
PS1='$([ -n "$TMUX" ] && tmux setenv TMUXPWD_$(tmux display -p "#I") $PWD)\u@\H:\w$ '
```

And to `~/.tmux.conf`, add the lines:

```
bind-key c run-shell 'tmux neww "cd $(tmux display -p "\$TMUXPWD_#I"); exec bash"'
bind-key % run-shell 'tmux splitw -h "cd $(tmux display -p "\$TMUXPWD_#I"); exec bash"'
bind-key '"' run-shell 'tmux splitw -v "cd $(tmux display -p "\$TMUXPWD_#I"); exec bash"'
```

Restart tmux.

**Sources**

See the section, "How can I open a new window in the same directory as the current window?" at http://tmux.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tmux/trunk/FAQ.

Note that the characters at the end of the .bashrc line had to be changed from the original at the link above to `'\u@\H:\w$ '` in order to properly display the complete bash prompt. See http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html for more info.

Comment: A better solution may exist? Note the following example. Assume X and Y are simlinks in ~. cd to ~/X and split window. Now from pane2, cd to ~/Y. Return to pane1 and split window again. Pane3's path becomes ~/Y but should be ~/X.